# How to get rid of warning "React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies ..." while keeping (intentionally) an empty array as dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to intentionally use useEffect to execute some code once when the component is mounted. Therefore, I use - on purpose - an empty array `[]` as dependencies.

Since I am using TypeScript (I at least think that's the reason) I always get the warning:
"React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies ..."

I do not want do add all the dependencies the precompiler is suggesting since that would lead to an unwanted execution of my useEffect hook.

What can I do to remove the warning message without adding (unwanted and, from my perspective, unnecessary, and even counterproductive) dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to, you can get rid of the warning by moving the dependencies out of the `useEffect` function body. This makes it impossible for the pre-compiler to detect the actual dependencies. Example:

```
const [a, setA] = useState<string>('abc');
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(a);
}, []);
```

Could become

```
const [a, setA] = useState<string>('abc');
function printA() {
    console.log(a);
}
useEffect(() => {
    printA();
}, []);
```

You should be aware of the side-effects though -- the warning has a good reason and your code might cause behavior that others might not expect.

Comment: I am not sure if I might be missing some "best practice" here. I am calling `setXYZ(...)` to update some varibales managed with `useState` whithin my useEffect hook. This update is supposed to happen once when the component is mounted. Since I use the useState-variable itself in the useEffect hook including it as dependency leads to an infinite loop. That is what I would like to avoid. I don't mind the precompiler checking per se. What can I do? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you fetch values from somewhere or why do you set the state values from within an effect?

Comment: That's a very good question. I actually combine the data provided by different props that I store "back" to the respective useState-variable. To give you a simplified example: string "text" = "Hello $user$", object "data" contains a "look-up-and-replace" information for $user$. And I "store back" the resulting string "Hello Tom" to string "text"

Comment: If this can be done synchronously and is a one-time thing that happens when the component first renders, I'd just put the code directly in `useState`'s argument (the initial value) and not even depend on an effect.